# Error Code : 1005 Can't create table 'custom_db2.durableprofile' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1005

can't create database

```
--------------------------------------------------------
create table DurableArticle(

    durable_code varchar(30) not null,
    durable_name varchar(100),
    durable_number varchar(20),
    durable_brandname varchar(125),
    durable_modelordetail varchar(125), 
    durable_price varchar(20),
    durable_entrance varchar(20),

    constraint durable_PK primary key (durable_code)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

---------------------------------------------


create table DurableProfile(

    profile_year integer not null,
    profile_status varchar(100),
    profile_note varchar(100),
    staff_id integer not null,
    owner_id integer not null,
    room_id integer not null,
    durable_code varchar(30) not null,

    constraint profile_PK primary key (profile_year,durable_code),
    constraint profile_FK1 foreign key (staff_id) references staff(staff_id),
    constraint profile_FK2 foreign key (owner_id) references owner(owner_id),
    constraint profile_FK3 foreign key (room_id) references room(room_id),
    constraint profile_Fk4 foreign key (durable_code) references durablearticle (durable_code)

)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you reference 3 tables in the second statement, which obviously do not exist (yet).
Remove the foreign keys or create those tables, then it works.

```
create table DurableProfile(

    profile_year integer not null, 
    profile_status varchar(100), 
    profile_note varchar(100), 
    staff_id integer not null, 
    owner_id integer not null, 
    room_id integer not null, 
    durable_code varchar(30) not null,

    constraint profile_PK primary key (profile_year,durable_code), 
    constraint profile_Fk4 foreign key (durable_code) references durablearticle (durable_code)

)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Thank you I'm forgot check primary key on Room Table